# Is there a more efficient way to get X11-style mouse-based, cross-application copy-and-paste for command-line use than "xinit xterm" or the like?

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen, mouse, clipboard

In some contexts, I want the ability to run `screen` and to copy and paste text between different windows (in the `screen` sense of that term, not the X11 window manager sense) using click-and-drag to copy and (ideally) middle-click to paste, as I would be able to do if I were running screen in an `xterm`, but don't have any particular need for any other graphical features. Starting up an X server just to be able to do this is an option (outside of unusual circumstances), but seems like overkill. Is there a straightforward way to get this sort of simple "mouse interacting with text" behavior without using X (ideally, without X having to even be installed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there’s [gpm](https://www.nico.schottelius.org/software/gpm/): it provides support for mice on Linux virtual terminals. It supports copy and paste, and also enables mouse usage in applications which support it (such as Midnight Commander).

It’s packaged in many distributions; look for a `gpm` package.

There’s also [consolation](https://salsa.debian.org/consolation-team/consolation) which is similar, but based on `libinput` (so it supports multitouch etc.).